# Product calculation by group in R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm currently working on transforming a dataset to take the product of each previous observation in a datatable. This is something that is implemented easy in excel but I am struggling to find a non-recursive solution to in data.table. The data in short form, ID has thousands of more levels and thousands of x's per ID in the real data. Each ID has the same number of X's.

```
| index | ID | X    |
|-------|----|------|
| 1     | 1  | 0.8  |
| 2     | 1  | 0.75 |
| 3     | 1  | 0.72 |
| 4     | 2  | 0.9  |
| 5     | 2  | 0.5  |
| 6     | 2  | 0.45 |
```

What I want to end up with is the following

```
| index | ID | X    | product |
|-------|----|------|---------|
| 1     | 1  | 0.8  | 0.8     |
| 2     | 1  | 0.75 | 0.6     |
| 3     | 1  | 0.72 | 0.432   |
| 4     | 2  | 0.9  | 0.9     |
| 5     | 2  | 0.5  | 0.45    |
| 6     | 2  | 0.45 | 0.2025  |
```

Where product is equal to x multiplied by all previous values of x for that particular ID. This can be done in a for loop however I am looking for a solution that leverages the use of data.table so this can be run on a cluster.

Reproducible data:

```
df <- fread('
 index  ID  X    
 1      1   0.8  
 2      1   0.75 
 3      1   0.72 
 4      2   0.9  
 5      2   0.5  
 6      2   0.45 
')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `cumprod`

```
# If data.table not already loaded, these steps are required first
# library(data.table)
# setDT(df)

df[, Xprod := cumprod(X), ID][]

#    index ID    X  Xprod
# 1:     1  1 0.80 0.8000
# 2:     2  1 0.75 0.6000
# 3:     3  1 0.72 0.4320
# 4:     4  2 0.90 0.9000
# 5:     5  2 0.50 0.4500
# 6:     6  2 0.45 0.2025
```

If you need to apply a function other than `prod`, you can use `frollapply`. For example, the code below gives the same result as the code above.

```
df[, Xprod := frollapply(X, 1:.N, prod, adaptive = TRUE), by = ID]
```

Comment: just do load the package `library(data.table)` and convert your data.frame into a data.table first `setDT(df)`

Comment: A bit more generalisable (to using other functions) would be: `df[, sapply(1:.N, function(i) prod(X[1:i])), by = ID]
`